# Nodejs cannot find global modules after npm upgrade

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed the last npm 5.5.1 on my Ubuntu local. I installed globally the modules that I frequently use (like express ecc...).
In this way in my package.json I leave "dependencies" blank and npm goes looking for modules in the right directory (/usr/lib/node_modules/). 
This worked with my last npm 3.10.10 but now something seems is changed.
When I try to run a app I got: "Cannot find module express". thanks

Comment: tried re-installing all your global modules? use this command to check global modules location "npm list -g"

Comment: I tried it but it's the same

Comment: have you upgraded nodejs as well?

Comment: Yes.I tried to install the old version of nodejs and npm but the problem persist. In the installation I did notice some GPG errors. Signature are not valid because public key is not available so is impossible to get from https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease.

Comment: maybe the problem is there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `--save` in your npm install, for save the packages in your package.json dependencies. Like that each time you run npm install he'll know the list of package to install in your project.

Example:

```
npm install express --save
npm install express --save-dev // for install in dev dependencies
```

Comment: I don't want create a node_modules folder  every time I create a project (in local)